# Pivot in sql server: Vertical to Horizontal data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Hi I have the following table that I would like to use the pivot function on:

```
Id|Number| Code
1 |  34  |abc12345
1 |  23  |xqwe6758
2 |  37  |ghut564hg
3 | 456  |ghut8695
3 |  39  |ghtuj678
3 |  22  |fsdifje12
```

And I want it to be displayed horizontally as the following:

```
Id| Code1    | Code2    | Code3
1 | abc12345 | xqwe6758 | null  
2 |ghut564hg | null     | null
3 |ghut8695  | ghtuj678 | fsdifje12


SELECT Id
      ,[Code1]
      ,[Code2]
      ,[Code3]
  FROM(SELECT Id,Code
        FROM [TableName] 
  )d
  pivot(
  max(Id)
  for Code in([Code1],[Code2],[Code3])
  )as piv;
```

This throws an invalid column name error on the Id column. Could someone help identify the error ?

Comment: @DanielCorzo : Since I have very random values in Code column, I don't want to hard-code the "Case" values as mentioned in that link. Would there be a work-around?

Comment: Is there a limit on max 3 codes?

Comment: @Shnugo: Yes I would have a maximum of 3 Codes per Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pivot as below:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select  
        id, code, 
        RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by id order by code) 
    from 
        yourtable1
) 
select * 
from cte
pivot ( max(code) for RowN in([1], [2], [3])) p
```

For varying columns you can use stuff to create columns list and then use dynamic SQL to run with varying columns... But it is available in various examples in SO itself...

Added my output:

[image]

Comment: It splits up code1 in a line, code 2 in another line instead of one row for ID number 1

Comment: That is your required output rite? Can you please clarify required output?

Comment: same line means same row with different columns right? That is what this query gives

Comment: Updated output of mine... If you have any other columns let me know that is causing this problem...

Comment: Can you provide me input samples with your third column as well?

Comment: I have updated my sample input table. I dont want that extra column in the output though

Comment: How you want to show the number? You want to transpose number column as well?

Comment: If you do not want to transpose the number column then select required columns in CTE as shown in my changed query -- see updated

Comment: Great that works ! Thank you. Could you also please provide an explanation of your query in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT, Code VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'abc12345')
,(1,'xqwe6758')
,(2,'ghut564hg')
,(3,'ghut8695')
,(3,'ghtuj678')
,(3,'fsdifje12');

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT Id
           ,'Code' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Code) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
           ,Code
    FROM @tbl
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Code) FOR ColumnName IN(Code1,Code2,Code3 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p
```

The result

```
Id  Code1       Code2       Code3
1   abc12345    xqwe6758    NULL
2   ghut564hg   NULL        NULL
3   fsdifje12   ghtuj678    ghut8695
```